# In Google App Engine/J, what is the maximum row count in a table?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Let's say, I would like to keep "chats" in a table. columns may be "from", "to" and "message" (all strings). what is the maximum row count in this table? What will happen after I exceed 20million rows? Is 20 million huge or small?

In general in Google App Engine form Java, what is the maximum row count in a table? What are the best practices?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your referring to the datastore, for all practical reasons the only limit is your budget, the more data you store you will pay more for storage.

---

In regard for query speed, the major overhead in query is the amount of items that query fetches, it takes almost the same time to retrive X items from 1,000 entities set and from 100,000,000.

There is a [very interesting video from Google IO 2008](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tx5gdoNpcZM) about the datastore (the indexes part is still relevant)

Comment: "for all practical reasons" let's say I filter 100 rows by a query from  1000 rows and let's assume that it takes 1ms. do you mean it took much less than 1000ms if my row count were 1 million? Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @lembas You ask about max row count

Comment: @lembas Query time scales with the number of results, not with the number of rows in the database. For reference, every single entity for every single app in App Engine is stored in a single Bigtable.

Answer (score 0):

You can store unlimited rows in datastore. However you should pay an attention to operate them. If your application tries to retrieve too many row, it will cause serious performance problem. (DeadlineExceededException)
So you had better do some devices about it. For example, fetch small size entities and loop it in client.